# keep value selected in option after page load or submit button click in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am putting `@` sign for getting the intellisence of the model properties but ASP.Net Core MVC is not allowing me to put `@` sign and it is getting just red once I put `@` sign in the below-posted Razor View code Select Tag.

Here:

```
@(item.DhoobiId==ViewBag.Customer_Id ? "selected='selected'" : "")

<select class="kt-selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Code Numbers" ng-model="item.Suit_Id" data-style="btn-brand" style="width:100%">
    @foreach (var item in dbContext.Customers.ToList())
    {
        <option value="@item.Customer_Id" @(item.DhoobiId==ViewBag.Customer_Id ? "selected='selected'" : "")>@item.Customer_Code_No</option>
    }
</select>
```

I tried to put `@` sign to get Model Properties. Just like we do in ASP.Net MVC.
In ASP.Net Core MVC is not being allowed this.

```
<select class="kt-selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Code Numbers" ng-model="item.Suit_Id" data-style="btn-brand" style="width:100%">
    @foreach (var item in dbContext.Customers.ToList())
    {
        <option value="@item.Customer_Id" @(item.DhoobiId==ViewBag.Customer_Id ? "selected='selected'" : "")>@item.Customer_Code_No</option>
    }
</select>
```

I expect the Option Value selected after the submit button is clicked. The value must be retained.

Comment: <select class="kt-selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Code Numbers" ng-model="item.Suit_Id" data-style="btn-brand" style="width:100%">
                                                        @foreach (var item in dbContext.Customers.ToList()){ <option value="@item.Customer_Id" @(item.DhoobiId==ViewBag.Customer_Id ? "selected='selected'" : "")>@item.Customer_Code_No</option> }
 </select>
  <span class="form-text text-muted">Please select Code No</span>

Comment: This code should be in the question and properly formatted so it can be read.

Answer (score 0):

I want to use my own **classes**, **dtos** as stuff like that to show how to manage and set option control in **view.cshtm**l.

Based on the following code, it is supposed to get all languages and then set one that the user selected.

1: a DTO for getting the languages:

```
    public class GetLanguagesServiceDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } // NameEnglish + NameNative => NameEnglish (NameNative)
}
```

2: a DTO for getting the language list as a list

```
public class ResultGetLanguagesServiceDto
{
    public List<GetLanguagesServiceDto> getLanguagesServiceDto { get; set; }
}
```

3: A **model** for setting several DTOs (I'm supposed that there are several models in DTOs style that are going to be used in one view.cshtml page)

```
    public class ModelGetInformation
{
    public ... { get; set; }
    public ... { get; set; }
    public ResultGetLanguagesServiceDto resultGetLanguagesServiceDto { get; set; }
}
```

4: Initializing model through a controller (I used the FACADE pattern, if you don't like using FACADE PATTERN structure, let's ignore it)

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //// Get languages List ...        
        return View(new ModelGetInformation
        {
            resultGetLanguagesServiceDto = _languagesFacade.GetLanguagesService.Execute(),
        });
    }
```

5: define your model and its namespace at the highest point of view page:

```
@using Endpoint.Site.Models.Users.GetInformation;
@model ModelGetInformation;
```

6: the main code! the following code shows you how to get all languages listed first, and then set the default value that the user has already selected.

```
   <select
                        class="form-select" id="selectLanguage">
                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                    @{
                        foreach (var lang in Model.resultGetLanguagesServiceDto.getLanguagesServiceDto)
                        {
                            <option value="@lang.Id" selected="@(lang.Id == Model.getUsersInformationServiceDto.LanguageId)">"@lang.Name"</option>
                        }
                    }
                </select>
```

Some tips:

1. you must use foreach because of getting your dynamic list
2. tag "selected" indicates which item will be selected at first
3. "Model.getUsersInformationServiceDto.LanguageId" will get the "language Id" that your client has already saved it in her/his profile